"The parameter type `T` must be valid for the static lifetime" Only when not in `async` block
This code fails to compile
use tokio_util::task::LocalPoolHandle;

pub struct Test<T> {
    thread_pool: LocalPoolHandle,
    writer_provider: T,
}

impl<T> Test<T>
{
    async fn initialize_threads(&mut self) {
        self.thread_pool.spawn_pinned(move || {

                Self::handle_log_event()

        });
    }
    async fn handle_log_event() -> () {
        print!("Logging event");
    }
}

error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/manager/test.rs:33:9
   |
33 | /         self.thread_pool.spawn_pinned(move || {
34 | |
35 | |                 Self::handle_log_event()
36 | |
37 | |         });
   | |          ^
   | |          |
   | |__________the parameter type `T` must be valid for the static lifetime...
   |            ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
   |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound
   |
29 | impl<T: 'static> Test<T>


However when i put the async function in an async block, then everything works fine with same behavior as if I followed the compiler recommendation and added the 'static lifetime
use tokio_util::task::LocalPoolHandle;

pub struct Test<T> {
    thread_pool: LocalPoolHandle,
    writer_provider: T,
}

impl<T> Test<T>
{
    async fn initialize_threads(&mut self) {
        self.thread_pool.spawn_pinned(move || {
           async {
                Self::handle_log_event().await
            }
        });
    }
    async fn handle_log_event() -> () {
        print!("Logging event");
    }
}


i was under the impression that the only thing async blocks do is return a future that resolves to the value returned from the block. So the two above code snippets should be equivalent. So why would one result in a compilation error?

I suspect that the future returned by handle_log_event is more restrictive than it needs to be and the async { } syntax realizes that it doesn't matter. Just a hunch though; lifetimes around async fns can be weird.

Besides the async fn sugar hiding an RPIT that captures the lifetime of Self, and the async block "sugar" hiding a "closure", this doesn't have anything to do with async at all: here is a minimal example of the problem without any async.

Actually we don't even need an RPIT in that example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=13714196145d507e5edb480ef0c6a1bc

Asked on URLO.
